# Mysql simple question : How to do this relationship?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, relationship

So basically there is a table containing the answers to the questions of a survey. A column at this table contain what sport the people practice, considering that one person can practice many sports, so we have a 1->n relationship.

If I am not mistaken, SportsPraticed (INT) will contain the INT corresponding to the chosen sport(s) (for example Baseball:1, Soccer:2 etc...)
But how can this be implemented given that multiple sports can be chosen?

How can such a relationship be established?

[image: relation]

Comment: What output are you looking for? Do you want to list a sport with all people who practice it? You must provide context.

Comment: My output expected is for a person, the list of the sports praticed